# JavaScript: Adding setInterval() dynamically in loop, and clearing each instance separately

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I want to loop over every element with a particular class, then add an interval and timeout to each element. The timeout will change its class in  n seconds and the interval will repeat x seconds.

However, I also want the user to stop the intervals individually by clicking on the element of their choice, rather than clearing all the Intervals (or the last timeout) at once. Is there a way to set individual Interval instances per iteration in a loop? And if so, how do you then refer to these instances individually later?

Noted where I get stuck in the logic:

```
 var myInterval;
 $('.my-elements').each(function(i){
    var thisElement = $(this)

    //add class every 2000 milliseconds
    //At a loss on how to make dynamic/relative to interation
    setInterval(function(){

      $(thisElement).addClass("active");
      //remove class after 200 milliseconds 
      var myInterval = setTimeout(function(){ $(thisElement).removeClass("active") },200)


    }, 2000)

    $(thisElement).click(function(){
      //AT A LOSS
      //stop interval for this element;
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since setting a timeout actually returns a numerical ID of the timer, you can simply store/cache the timer associated with each element in a custom jQuery `.data()` object.

Note that in the example below I have set the timer from your `200ms` to `1000ms` so that you can see the changes better.

```js
$('.my-elements').each(function(i) {
  var $thisElement = $(this);

  //add class every 2000 milliseconds
  setInterval(function() {

    $thisElement.addClass("active");
    var classRemovalTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      $thisElement.removeClass("active")
    }, 1000);

    // Store this class removal timer in jQuery data object
    $thisElement.data('class-removal-timer-id', classRemovalTimer);

  }, 2000);

  $thisElement.click(function() {
    // Check if timer exists for the element.
    // If it does, clear it
    var classRemovalTimer = $thisElement.data('class-removal-timer-id')
    if (classRemovalTimer) {
       window.clearTimeout(classRemovalTimer);
    }
  })

})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-elements">1</div>
<div class="my-elements">2</div>
<div class="my-elements">3</div>
<div class="my-elements">4</div>
<div class="my-elements">5</div>
```

Some additional pro-tips:

- You are double wrapping your `$(this)` element, by first assigning it to `thisElement` and then wrapping `$(thisElement)` later. You only need to do that once
- Read up about how you can take advantage of [jQuery's `.data()` object/store](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Okay. Interesting. I will try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the setInterval call to myInterval and remove the global variable `myInterval` rather than the setTimeout, also no need to wrap your element in another jquery call

```
$('.my-elements').each(function(i){
    var thisElement = $(this);

    //add class every 2000 milliseconds
    var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        thisElement.addClass("active");
        //remove class after 200 milliseconds -- At a loss on how to make dynamic/relative to interation
        setTimeout(function(){ $(thisElement).removeClass("active") },200);
    }, 2000)

    thisElement.click(function(){
        clearTimeout(myInterval);
    });
})
```

Comment: I confused "Interval" and "Timeout" and updated the question, but your answer still seems to apply. Thank you. So, `clearTimeout(myInterval)` still applies to each iteration individually if in the loop, and doesn't get erased on the next iteration?  Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the timer for each dynamic element individually by using `setInterval`. `setInterval` is not a jQuery function. It is a built-in JavaScript function.

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Shalitha/q1z8x3w9/1/) for a perfect example,

```js
var elementArray = [];
function timer(selector, element) {
    var self = $(selector);
    var sec = 0;
    var text = self.find('span.timeout').text();
    
    elementArray.forEach(function(item) {
          //console.log(item);
            if(item.element != element){
              $("#"+item.element).removeClass("timerOn");
              $("#"+item.element).addClass("timerPause");
            }
            
    });
    
    elementArray = [];
    
 
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        sec++;
        
        var elementID = element;
        
        
        if($("#"+elementID).hasClass("timerOn")){
         //console.log(sec);
          //console.log(elementID);
         $("#"+elementID).find('span.timeout').text(text+ '(' + sec + ')');
        }else{
         window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
        
    }, 1000);
    
    var obj = {
     controller : interval,
      element : element
    };
    
    elementArray.push(obj);
}


$("body").on('click', '.element', function() {

  if($(this).hasClass("timerOn")){
     $(this).removeClass("timerOn");
      $(this).addClass("timerPause");
    }else if($(this).hasClass("timerPause")){
     $(this).removeClass("timerPause");
      $(this).find('span.timeout').text($(this).find('span.timeout').text().replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, ""));
    }
    else{
     $(this).addClass("timerOn");
      timer(this, $(this).attr('id'));
    }

    
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <button class="element" id="el1">
    <span class="timeout">time</span>
 </button>
  <button class="element" id="el2">
    <span class="timeout">time</span>
  </button>
   <button class="element" id="el3">
    <span class="timeout">time</span>
  </button>
   <button class="element" id="el4">
    <span class="timeout">time</span>
  </button>
</div>
```